# Unable to Define Auto Scaling for SageMaker Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, scaling, endpoint, amazon-sagemaker

I have deployed an AWS endpoint using a Docker container (I followed [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/docker-containers.html)).

Everything is working perfectly but now I need to put it in production and define an auto scaling strategy.

I tried 2 things:

1. AWS console but the auto scaling button is greyed
   out.
2. The method described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/endpoint-auto-scaling-add-code-apply.html). My endpoint name
   is `EmbeddingEndpoint` and my variant name is `SimpleVariant`. So my
   final command is

```
aws application-autoscaling put-scaling-policy \
--policy-name scalable_policy_for_embedding \
--policy-type TargetTrackingScaling \
--resource-id endpoint/EmbeddingEndpoint/variant/SimpleVariant \
--service-namespace sagemaker \
--scalable-dimension sagemaker:variant:DesiredInstanceCount \
--target-tracking-scaling-policy-configuration file://policy_config.json
```

but I get this result :

```
An error occurred (ObjectNotFoundException) when calling the PutScalingPolicy operation: 
No scalable target registered for service namespace: sagemaker, resource ID: 
endpoint/EmbeddingEndpoint/variant/SimpleVariant, scalable dimension: 
sagemaker:variant:DesiredInstanceCount
```

Does someone have another solution, or is it that I didn't set the variable well ?
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sagemaker` service-namespace does not have any registered scaling targets. You need to first run `register-scalable-target` before running `put-scaling-policy`.

```
aws application-autoscaling register-scalable-target \
    --service-namespace sagemaker \
    --scalable-dimension sagemaker:variant:DesiredInstanceCount \
    --resource-id endpoint/EmbeddingEndpoint/variant/SimpleVariant
```